# Scaling for windowed differentiator FIR filters

Tags: filter-design, finite-impulse-response, frequency-response, time-domain

I recently took a dive into DSP and I was wondering what the appropriate scaling factor for a wide-band differentiator is.
Let's derive the impulse response of such a differentiator.
$$\begin{aligned}
h_{wb}(n)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\omega_c}^{\omega_c}H_{\text{ideal}}(j\omega)e^{j\omega n}d\omega\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\omega_c}^{\omega_c}j\omega e^{j\omega n}d\omega\\
&=\frac{j}{2\pi}\left[ \frac{1}{jn}\omega e^{j\omega n} \right]_{-\omega_c}^{\omega_c} - \frac{j}{2\pi}\int_{-\omega_c}^{\omega_c}\frac{1}{jn}e^{j\omega n}d\omega\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi n}\left[\omega e^{j\omega n} \right]_{-\omega_c}^{\omega_c} - \frac{1}{2\pi n}\int_{-\omega_c}^{\omega_c}e^{j\omega n}d\omega\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi n}\left(\omega_c e^{j\omega_c n} - (-\omega_c) e^{-j\omega_c n} \right) - \frac{1}{2\pi n}\left[ \frac{1}{jn}e^{j\omega n} \right]_{-\omega_c}^{\omega_c}\\
&=\frac{\omega_c\cos(\omega_c n)}{\pi n} - \frac{1}{2\pi n^2}\left( \frac{1}{j}e^{j\omega_c n}-\frac{1}{j}e^{-j\omega_c n} \right)\\
&=\frac{\omega_c\cos(\omega_c n)}{\pi n} - \frac{\sin(\omega_c n)}{\pi n^2}
\end{aligned}$$
So (after applying de l'Hôpital's rule) the impulse response of a wide-band differentiator is

$$h(n)=\begin{cases}\frac{\omega_c\cos(\omega_cn)}{\pi n}-\frac{\sin(\omega_cn)}{\pi n^2}, & n\neq 0\\
0 &n=0\end{cases},$$
where $\omega_c$ is the cut-off frequency.
I also want to apply a window to this infinite impulse response, e.g., a Blackman window
$$h_{tot}=h(n)w(n).$$
[image: Time domain with f0=20Hz]
[image: Frequency Domain with fs=1kHz, fc=25Hz]

But what I get is a much more damped response (see Figure 1 for time domain and 2 for [linear] frequency domain) very much like in [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70272/attenuation-of-the-central-difference-differentiator).
I also plotted the result of using a Parks McClellan design with

```matlab
    bPmc = firpm(N,[0,fc,fc+5,fs/2]/(fs/2),[0,fc/(fs/2),0,0]*pi,'differentiator');
```

where `N` is the filter order, `fs` is the sampling time, and $\omega_c=2\pi f_c$.
This works as expected when the noisy signal is filtered using

```matlab
    dydtPmc = filter(bPmc,dt,yNoisy);
```

where `dt` is the sampling time and `yNoisy` is the noisy signal.

However, the scaling provided in the above-mentioned post does not lead to the desired result when I use the windowed design.
In several resources, I found, e.g., in this [blog post](https://wirelesspi.com/design-of-a-discrete-time-differentiator/), or [this book](https://www.analog.com/en/education/education-library/scientist_engineers_guide.html) (Eq. 16.4) it is mentioned that scaling of the coefficients might necessary but I cannot find any information on how to determine it.
I suggest it must have something to do with the sampling time, since damping increases as the sampling time decreases.
This makes sense to me, e.g., when we look at a central difference that has coefficients $[1,0,-1]$ that are obtained with `N=2` (without windowing) in the first equation above. This obviously has to be scaled with `1/(2*dt)=1/(N*dt)` to get the correct result. But how do I generalize this?
I tried several combinations of scaling factors but none of them worked.
I also thought that it could be solved by requiring that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}H(j\omega)\bigg\vert_{\omega=0}=1$$
and using the characteristic of the DTFT that a derivative in the frequency domain corresponds to a multiplication with $n$ in the time domain, i.e.,
$$j\frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}H(j\omega)\bullet-\circ nh(n) $$
e.g., taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform#:%7E:text=Derivative%20in%20frequency)
but that also does not do the trick since I would need to convolve the FFT of the window with the impulse response.

Can anyone help me?

**EDIT**: I just found out that the custom design works when my sample rate is not as high. For the examples shown, I had $f_s=1000$Hz which was much much higher than the cutoff frequency $f_c=25$Hz. When I use, e.g. $f_s=100$Hz, the custom filter is similar to the Parks McClellan output. This somehow makes sense. I guess if the "overall" system would need to run at such a high frequency, one would decimate anyway and re-interpolate afterwards? I still don't see, however, why this has such an effect on the magnitude response.

Comment: If $\omega_\mathrm{c} \ne \pi$, then the impulse response of the differentiator should be:

$$h[n]=\begin{cases}\frac{\cos(\omega_\mathrm{c} n)}{n}-\frac{\sin(\omega_\mathrm{c} n)}{\omega_\mathrm{c} n^2}, & n\neq 0\\
0 &n=0\end{cases},$$

What you are differentiating is

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} n} \, \frac{\sin(\omega_\mathrm{c} n)}{\omega_\mathrm{c} n}$$

Comment: And I would use a better window, such as the Kaiser window.  Or at least use the Hamming window.

Comment: I gotta add a correction.  I was thinking "Bartlett window", which isn't so good.  The Blackman window might be okay.

Comment: Do you mean

$$j\frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}H(e^{j\omega})\bigg\vert_{\omega=0}= \mathcal{Z}\big\{ n \, h[n] \big\}$$

?

Comment: I added the derivation, which i am fairly certain is correct. I also added reference to the DTFT derivative relation. Using a Blackman wIndow could be up to debate but is not the focus of the question. However, it does scale the impulse response and thus probably also the frequency response.

Comment: I understand your first comment. However, I do not see my mistake in the derivation. The result is almost the same but for a factor of $\frac{\pi/\omega_c}$? I also tried scaling, e.g. by this factor but to no avail

Comment: I also found out (and edited above) that if I decrease the sample rate, the differentiator works fine.